# Sympy subs not outputting a substituted expression?

Tags: python, sympy

I am using sympy to differentiate a function in python. After differentiating the function, I would like to add in the numerical value of the variable that I differentiated with. However, using .subs() does not return a different answer. Does anyone have an idea s to what my issue is?

Code:

```
CA1 = CA0 * sympy.exp(-(A1*sympy.exp(-E1/(R*T)))*t)
dCa_dA12 = diff(CA1, A1)
print("No substitution:", dCa_dA12)
dCa_1 = dCa_dA12.subs(A1, theta[0])
print("Substitution:", dCa_1)
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Comment: This usually means it didn't recognize your symbol. You should show how you defined `A1`.

Comment: Or maybe `theta[0]` doesn't contain a numerical value but the symbol `A1`?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and was tinkering around a bit:

This works:

```
>>> sympify("k").evalf(subs={"k":1})
1.00000000000000
```

This doesn't work:

```
>>> sympify("k+x").evalf(subs={"k":1})
k + x
```

This again works:

```
>>> sympify("k+x").evalf(subs={"k":1, "x":2})
3.00000000000000
```

So it seems the substitution doesn't work if the result is not a number.  Strangely, this only applies to the `subs` part:

```
>>> sympify("2/3*x")
2*x/3
>>> sympify("2/3*x").evalf()
0.666666666666667*x
```

This looks like a bug to me. At least, it should be documented properly.